# MATLAB LSIM initial conditi

Tags: matlab, function, state-space

*Let x(0) = 0 and u(t) = 2, for t >= 0. Obtain a plot of y(t) for 0 <= t <= 20 using the lsim command.*

My `sys` function is ready but I cannot set the initial values in the question above. How can I do this?

This is my code:

```
lsim(sys1,u,t)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [documentation for `lsim`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/lsim.html):

> `lsim(sys,u,t,x0)` further specifies an initial condition `x0` for the
>   system states. This syntax applies only when `sys` is a state-space
>   model. `x0` is a vector whose entries are the initial values of the
>   corresponding states of `sys`.

So you need to know the states of your system and their respective initial conditions.